# Join but return ALL records from Table

Tags: php, sql, database

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` INNER JOIN `table2` ON table1.messageid=table2.messageid WHERE `venue_active` = 1
```

The above works fine but it only returns fields where both tables have a messageid field.

My problem is that I need it to return ALL fields from Table1 reguardless if it has a messageid match in table2 or not.

So, in other words I need ALL records to be returned from Table1 and all records from Table2 where there's a messageid that matches both.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this not what `LEFT JOIN` is for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) rather

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    `table1` LEFT JOIN 
        `table2` ON table1.messageid=table2.messageid 
WHERE   `venue_active` = 1
```

That said, it will only work if venue_active is also part of table1, and not table2.

Have a look at the different scenarios

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64fd1/7)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT` join rather than `INNER`

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table1.messageid=table2.messageid 
WHERE `venue_active` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you need a `LEFT JOIN` instead, or

a `FULL OUTER JOIN` workaround for MySQL:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM
  table1 a
LEFT JOIN
  table2 b ON a.messageid = b.messageid
WHERE a.venue_active = 1
UNION
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM
  table1 a
RIGHT JOIN
  table2 b ON a.messageid = b.messageid;
WHERE a.venue_active = 1
```